# How to read silently?

Tags: reading

I am not a native English speaker. I could understand what they spoke on TV programs (such as Discovery and National Geographic) , but I dont know how to read books silently. I tried to practice first by reading out loud (I tried to follow the reading tapes). However, when I read out loud, I couldn't understand the difficult sentences; and the most important thing is I couldn't transfer my reading out loud to reading silently. Could you show me how to read silently ? Also do you think should I just keep reading and reading (ignoring the understanding) until one day it will click when the amount of reading is large enough) or  should I try to understand every sentence ?

Thank for your help

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  When you read silently the language of the text is irrelevant as you are not verbalising the text.

Comment: You should read books whose words and sentences you understand, even if that means starting with books for children, and gradually working up to books for adults.

Comment: @TRomano That seems like good advice, but it isn't effective. Reason is that kid's books still use a very broad vocabulary and complex grammatical constructions.

Comment: @Araucaria: It's more effective than reading books with an even broader vocabulary and even more complex grammatical constructions, where one is totally at sea.

Comment: @TRomano Yes, agreed. But graded readers are the best! :)

Comment: @Araucaria: In a grading reading approach, I wouldn't use a reader that had "adapted" classic works of literature for younger readers. Books actually written for native-English preschoolers, for  kids in elementary and middle-school, and for so-called "young-adults", are preferable. Ideally they would be award-winning books widely read and enjoyed by native speakers.

Comment: @TRomano No use if you can't understand them, though. They'll be well over Advanced level.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with graded readers . But should I try to understand all the auditory inputs first before reading ?

Comment: @Chemunka  :    I tried to get silent reading by practicing with the audiobooks first, but so far I still couldn't be able to read silently.  I dont know if I just need to keep reading out loud and one day the silent reading will come naturally or do I need to do something else for it to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People often mock someone who can't [read without moving his lips](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22read%20without%20moving%20his%20lips%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which is seen as a sign of low intelligence and/or literacy (reading skills). But it's just an outward sign of...

> [**subvocalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subvocalization)
>     *[which] is a **natural process** when reading and helps to reduce cognitive load, and it helps the mind to access meanings to enable it to comprehend and remember what is read.*
>
> *Subvocalizing is an **inherent part of reading** and understanding a word, and micro-muscle tests suggest that subvocalizing is **impossible to permanently eliminate.***

Since language is primarily a *spoken* phenomenon, and humans were able to speak/listen for tens if not hundreds of millennia before anyone even thought of *writing*, it seems more than likely we've evolved specific neurological mechanisms to facilitate the earlier process.

*Text to Speech* software is getting pretty good these days, and I'd advise OP to try using it *at the same time as reading the text*. Native speakers learn to read by listening to a parent/teacher reading while the child views/reads the corresponding text. If no helpful native speaker is available for you as a learner, software assistance is a useful alternative.

In short, I think whether your primary goal is to *listen, speak, read,* or *write* a foreign language, it's best to focus on the *auditory* dimension. So long as you've got *some* idea of the actual meaning, your ability to recognise and understand previously unfamiliar vocabulary and syntax will probably progress faster if you emulate the "natural" approach. If you always stop to *think* about things (consult dictionaries, etc.), learning English will be about as much fun as learning the first 10,000 digits of π. And the chances of you achieving your goal will be equally slim (it's [doable,](http://math-fail.com/2010/03/memorizing-pi-world-records-and-techniques.html) but I don't recommend it).

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful to know that I should focus on the auditory dimension. But sometimes I dont know what they were talking about on TV programs b/c I think I lacked some vocab and background knowledge which comes from reading. But when I switched to reading, I couldn't be able to read b/c I think I should understand the auditory inputs first. So I just kept switching back and forth and wasted a lot of time.

Comment: Your own text here clearly shows that you're already quite competent in *written* English - possibly because you can read/write *at your own pace*. You can't normally control how fast "real" speech comes at you (though of course you can *speak* haltingly), but it might be worth noting that most text-to-speech software allows you to control the reading speed. Which emulates the natural process whereby parents and teachers tend to read slowly when they're trying to introduce a child to the written form.